# NSUserDefaults objectForKey sometimes nil

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I've just noticed that a key that exists in my `**NSUserDefaults**`
is returning nil quite often.  It seems about half the time it's
correct and the other half it's not.  I say half the time, but I dont
mean that its flip-flopping, its just 40-50% I see it not work.
When I write the initial value, I call synchronize immediately.
I use this key as the applications
revision I set when a new user signs up.

The following code returns nil:

```
#define kDBrevision  @"revision"

NSString *rev = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kDBrevision];
```

When I launch the app and just monitor the value (without
writing any NSUserDefaults), the value sometimes is valid
with no modifications to the NSUserDefaults at all.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *r = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kDBrevision];
    NSLog(@"revision %@", r);
    _exit(1);
```

I have no idea why this is happening.  Im running iOS 10 on my
device connected to Xcode 8.2.1.  Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT:
I started talking to apple about fixing this and found out that if you have
file protection complete turned on, it can be the cause of this issue
showing up from time to time, however apple told me that my particular
case (which is the only one I was sure of at this time) is a bug.
The case is when you use Xcode to launch the app on the device it should
not fail like this and it occasionally does.  No idea when or if it will
be fixed.  Instead I moved my critical strings from the defaults to
the keychain instead.

Comment: Probably you need to check if you save nil value to your `NSUserDefault`, there's nothing like half time correct half time wrong in code, its on your code only

Comment: Have you missed [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] while setting?

Comment: I verified that I am not writing nil.  And yes, when I write a new value, I call syncrhonize.

Comment: That new value you saying might be nil, try print it before set, or check whether that `setObject` code got called anywhere else, call `syncrhonize` is usually not needed

Comment: I am not setting it anywhere else in the code.  After finding this problem, I immediately print the value when the launch starts and do NOTHING else (except print its value and exit for debug purposes).  If I keep running it over and over, I see it sometimes is valid, sometimes nil

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be an Xcode 8 and/or iOS 10 bug. I ran into it myself and conclusively narrowed the case to UserDefaults intermittently returning nil when in fact there was data for the key. Specifically, I set the data once, then removed the set logic and executed only the get logic, repeatedly, and sometimes got values, sometimes got nil.

I changed my Run scheme to use Release configuration and ran the app on device without the debugger attached and the issue disappeared, that is, the get logic produced the correct value every time I executed it (~30 times).

Here is some more discussion:

[iOS 10 with XCode 8 GM caused NSUserDefaults to intermittently not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457564/ios-10-with-xcode-8-gm-caused-nsuserdefaults-to-intermittently-not-work)

[iOS 10, NSUserDefaults Does Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840288/ios-10-nsuserdefaults-does-not-work)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48700

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143155#143155

Answer (score 0):

try below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Swift 3.0

```
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Obective - C

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Beware, as per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize), this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.