# NSUserDefault issue with iOS10

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Have a similar problem with this [iOS 10, NSUserDefaults Does Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840288/ios-10-nsuserdefaults-does-not-work)

Seems like NSUserDefault is not working in iOS 10 simulator when it previously run iOS 8 or 9. But my question is, would it be okay on the device itself? When it is downloaded by the user using iOS10, would it lend to some bug or crash?

Comment: Based on comments on the question you posted, the AppStore version of your application should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefault will work fine on device, i am using it in my app. I haven't faced any such issues. Try to run your app in a device, i am sure you won't face any issues.
If possible please share the code, there is a possibility that you might be missing on something

Comment: It may a comment, instead of answer.